# Laravel routing white page with Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8.

I'm trying to save ip addresses who visited the page. I can save it to the database. But there is a white page problem on page. How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

web.php

```
Route::get('/', [IpController::class,'addData'], function () {
    $slides = App\Slide::all();
    $themes = App\Theme::all();            
    return view('tema.kurumsal.index', compact('slides','themes'));
});
```

IpController.php

```
class IpController extends Controller
{
    //

    function addData(Request $req)
    {
        $ip = new Ip;
        $ip->ip = $req->ip();
        $ip->cihaz = $req->userAgent();
        $ip->url = $req->getRequestUri();
        $ip->save();
 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "a white page problem", what is a white page problem? Do you mean that all you're getting is a blank page? That's because you're trying to use both a controller and a callback. That's not how routes work. You should use either a controller or a callback. It looks to me like what you want is a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) to record the IP address instead of a controller.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 3rd parameter on `Route::get`, so what is that `function` doing ? This is the [Source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bf3d5e319f0bd928a493222adb1acd9d23c1db68/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L138-L148).

You have a white page because you are not returning a `view` or data on your `IpController`.

Have another look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#available-router-methods). There is no 3rd parameter.

---

Your code should be like this:

```php
Route::get('/', [IpController::class,'addData']);
```

And your controller:

```php
class IpController extends Controller
{
    public function addData(Request $req)
    {
        $ip = new Ip;
        $ip->ip = $req->ip();
        $ip->cihaz = $req->userAgent();
        $ip->url = $req->getRequestUri();
        $ip->save();
        
        $slides = \App\Slide::all();
        $themes = \App\Theme::all();            
        return view('tema.kurumsal.index', compact('slides','themes'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: Class "App\Http\Controllers\App\Slide" not found

Comment: I have edited the code, see again. I have added a missing `\`. You can also `use` it, so it would be `use App\Slide;` and `use App\Theme;`, and in your code it would be `Slide::all();` and `Theme::all();`. This is basic PHP so you can fix it yourself too.

Comment: I added. Very interesting. I have the same problem.

Comment: What problem do you have ?

Comment: I added. `use App\Slide;` Error: Class "App\Http\Controllers\App\Slide" not found

Comment: You have something wrong with your setup then, it should work. This is normal PHP code that you should be able to handle in your project as we have no information about it. Maybe composer is working bad. Try doing `\App\Slide::all();` as my answer instead of `use` and see if it works.

Comment: ParseError
syntax error, unexpected token "::", expecting "," or ";"

Comment: Yeah, you have something wrong with your laravel setup. I think it is related to composer as this is autoloading stuff that it is getting wrong... you should update your question with your new code.